# Make an options form in Delphi

Tags: delphi, forms

I want my Form1 to have a Options button that opens up Form2. In Form2, there will be 3 Radio buttons. When a radio button is pushed, I need one of my procedures to check using:

```
if (RadioButton1.Pushed) then begin
```

for it to continue with one portion of the code, or if Radiobutton2 is pushed, a different portion, and so on. The thing is, I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.  We aren't going to do your schoolwork for you.

Comment: You have no idea where to start? Start by putting the option button on Form1. If you've already done that, then you DO know where to start, so what's next? Which part of the task are you really having trouble with? Talking about a problem will help YOU understand it better, as well as everyone else.

Comment: I know that the Delphi help is slow in recent versions, but it is surely still faster than going to StackOverflow for answers - so why not try it first? This would help you determine that radio buttons do not have a Pushed property, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
if Form2.RadioButton1.Checked then
begin
  // Do something
end else
if Form2.RadioButton2.Checked then
begin
  // Do something else
end;
```

If this is going to be a bigger application, you should consider creating a global *settings object*, which can be changed by your options screen and is read by the procedures which need to know about certain settings.

**Important:** Directly accessing your forms from all over your code just increases coupling. When your application get's a little large it'll be a nightmare to maintain it.

```
// Form2
Config.DoSomething = RadioButton1.Checked
Config.DoSomethingElse = RadioButton2.Checked

// Form1
if Config.DoSomething then
begin
  // Do something
end else
if Config.DoSomethingElse then
begin
  // Do something else
end;
```

You could also add methods to your `config`uration object to save the settings to disk and reload them the next time your application starts.

Others suggested using a **RadioGroup**, but personally I don't like them as a long term solution, because I find them hard to adapt to my personal UI needs. (Mostly borders and distances) They may also become problematic if someday you want to reorder the items or insert a new item anywhere else than the end: Suddenly `ItemIndex` 2 means something completly different :) But as a quick-and-dirty solution they sure are useful.

Answer (score 5):

Might be easier to use a RadioGroup.  Then, you can just set your options by adding to the Items list in the Object Inspector.  You can tell which button has been set by looking at the ItemIndex like:

```
Case MyRadioGroup.ItemIndex of
  1: DoSomething;
  2: DoSomethingElse;
  3: DoAnotherThing;
End;
```

You don't have to use a RadioGroup.  All the buttons in any windowed control will have the mutual exclusion property that you expect a set of RadioButtons to have.

Jack

Comment: Keep in mind that the item index starts counting at zero, not one.

Answer (score 2):

So to re-phrase your question slightly, you are saying that

> Pressing a radio button puts my application into a certain state.
>   Later, based on that state, I want some specific code to run.

When phrased like this it becomes very simple. In the case of Jack's answer, he suggests (quite rightly) that a simple way (to query the state) is to use a Radio Group. The ItemIndex property tells you the state of the buttons.